# SQLite Command Line - remove migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rake, database-migration

I have an issue with my Rails app database which now prevents me from completing any migrations.

I've run the following on my command line with the following results -

PRAGMA table_info(events);

```
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|title|varchar|0||0
2|location|varchar|0||0
3|date|date|0||0
4|time|time|0||0
5|description|text|0||0
6|organised_by|varchar|0||0
7|created_at|datetime|1||0
8|updated_at|datetime|1||0
9|user_id|integer|0||0
10|image_file_name|varchar|0||0
11|image_content_type|varchar|0||0
12|image_file_size|integer|0||0
13|image_updated_at|datetime|0||0
14|category_id|integer|0||0
15|url|varchar|0||0
16|number_of_spaces|integer|0||0
17|price|integer|0||0
18|is_free|boolean|0||0
19|organiser_profile|url|0||0
```

The issue here is with No 19 on this table -

```
 19|organiser_profile|url|0||0
```

Url is not an acceptable data type which was inputted in error. I believe this is the stumbling block preventing my database from committing any further migrations.

I'm fairly new to Rails and have never manually amend a database before. What I want to do is the following -

1. Delete / remove / dump - No 19 from my Events table. The entire
   line has to be gone.
2. Check what is in the database before I perform a rake db:drop (this app is in development so there won't be
       much
3. Before I perform the following action -
                   bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate, I want to briefly understand what consequences could come from this

I'm pretty sure this is what is required to fix this issue and allow me to perform migrations again and move forward with my app. I've never done any of the above before and would be extremely grateful for any assistance on this process.

Comment: You have an existing Rails app that is set up with a table that contains a column that is a `url` type and you're trying to get it running on top of SQLite? Where is `organiser_profile` defined, `schema.rb`? What database is this app meant to be used with?

Comment: No, the column is organiser_profile the type I used was url which was invalid. I now need to remove this from my database completely. In schema.rb I get the following message - '# Could not dump table "events" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass'. This is obviously because of the migration error - there's no other possible reason I can think of (I've checked everything). The app is an event site - creating/booking events.

Comment: Yeah but where did this `organiser_profile` column come from? Did you create it manually? Are you trying to build an application on top of an existing SQLite database?

Comment: No, the column was generated via migration. It's the last migration I put through which worked. Every one since hasn't worked.

Comment: So that migration only half worked: it added the column with a bad type but didn't successfully regenerate `schema.rb`, right? Delete the offending migration, remove the column by hand (`alter table t drop column c` from inside `sqlite3`), recreate the migration with the proper column type, and move on.

Comment: When I attempt to drop the column on the command line I keep getting an error. Having looked at this I'm not sure that SQLite allows me to drop a column. Any thoughts on which way I can go with this now?

Comment: SQLite might want to you copy the table (without the offending column), drop the original, and rename the copy to implement `drop column`. If you don't have any data in the table then you could just drop the whole table and recreate it without the bad column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not in production yet or in danger of losing valuable information so just check out the db file from github from before the erroneous migration.

```
git checkout <commit> file
```

Then fix the migration that's erroneous then run migrations again with rake db:migrate. There's no need in this case to be trying to manually edit the table from the command line, unnecessary.

Comment: I tried something like this with the git command 'git add --all && git stash && git stash drop' and reopened my file. The schema was showing but when I tried another migration the error came back.

Comment: Just delete the schema (you don't need to do this but just do it anyway) and checkout the database from the very beginning then run all migrations again. That is seriously all you need to do

Comment: Delete the whole schema file?